# Are there any related groups of satellites that are in a line of 6 or more in a row?

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbit

02/03/20 0450hrs, in Bradford, West Yorkshire, Uk. I saw a satellite going across the sky, it was not too bright and was followed by another and then 4 more they were equally spaced. I would say they were 2-4 miles apart, a third of the sky apart if that makes sense. They were travelling West to East, they were following the same trajectory and following a straight path.
Does any one know what this could have been?

Answer (score 4):

Very likely you have seen Starlink Satellites. A view we all have more often in the future...

Assuming you mean 0450 local which is more or less greenwich-time which does not differ much from UTC.

Just one thing: They are around 100 km appart ;-)

Plot for 02/03/20 0450hrs, Bradford, West Yorkshire, UK. *click for full size view*

[image: 02/03/20 0450hrs, in Bradford, West Yorkshire, Uk.]

Comment: `+1` for the snazzy plot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, loads! You can see the StarLink trains at [Heavens Abve](https://heavens-above.com/StarLink.aspx):

[image: StarLink satellite trains]

Answer (score 0):

Supplemental answer to

> Are there any related groups of satellites that are in a line of 6 or more in a row?

<s>Yes</s> No, (while) the [A-train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-train_(satellite_constellation)) is a bunch of satellites in a row, it seems that Wikipedia says there are only 5 even though the picture shows six.

> The A-train (from Afternoon Train) is a satellite constellation of **five Earth observation satellites** of varied nationality in sun-synchronous orbit at an altitude of 705 km (438 mi) above the Earth.
>
> The orbit, at an inclination of 98.14°, crosses the equator each day at around 1:30 pm solar time, giving the constellation its name (the "A" stands for "afternoon"[2]) and crosses the equator again on the night side of the Earth, at around 1:30 am.
>
> They are spaced a few minutes apart from each other so their collective observations may be used to build high-definition three-dimensional images of the Earth's atmosphere and surface.

**Did you see the A-train?**

Ignoring the not six problem, it's still *probably not*, because they move in a polar orbit so would be North-South or South-North, and the highest passes would be 1:30 AM local time (the other half of the Sun-synchronous 1:30 PM orbit)

[image]