# Which satellite constellations are already operational in LEO (Low Earth Orbit)?

Tags: artificial-satellite, low-earth-orbit, starlink, satellite-constellation

I am researching information on active and operational constellations in LEO (Low Earth Orbit) but from what I can see, many missions are still only planned (e.g. OneWeb, Amazon) and the only one currently operational seems to be Starlink from SpaceX. Is that true or are there more satellite constellations in LEO? Is there a webpage where I can see the list of LEO satellite constellations?

Note that I have referred to Starlink, Amazon, and OneWeb, but I am talking about constellations in general, not only about internet-from-space ones. Also, I am interested only in constellations with at least 5 satellites.

Comment: GPS, Galileo, Glonass, Iridium, Iridium Next, Sentinels, Meteosats;  just a few that come to mind.

Comment: GPS, Galileo, Glonass, and Meteosats are in a geostationary orbit, so not in LEO. I was not aware of Iridium! Sentinels consists only of two satellites, and I am looking for constellations with at least 5 satellites. Forgot to specify that in the question, I will edit it

Comment: None of those satellites are in geostationary, or even geosynchronous orbits; they're all lower than that, but you are correct in that they're still well above LEO.

Comment: @notovny you are right, actually all the navigation satellite system are in MEO, my bad

Comment: Totally different question and a "choreography" more than a constellation, but you may or may not want to count it: [Are there any related groups of satellites that are in a line of 6 or more in a row?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41770/12102)

Comment: @PcMan what exactly am I ridiculously wrong about?

Comment: @cholo14 the a-train is still a thing ain't it?

Comment: @DekoRevinio what do you mean?

Comment: @cholo14 " a convoy of "A-Train" satellites has emerged as one of the most powerful tools scientists have for understanding our planet's changing climate.

The formation of satellites - which currently includes Aqua, CloudSat, Cloud-Aerosol Lidar and Infrared Pathfinder Satellite Observations (CALIPSO) and Aura satellites - barrels across the equator each day at around 1:30 p.m. local time each afternoon, giving the constellation its name; the "A" stands for "afternoon." " https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/a-train/a-train.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a webpage where I can see the list of LEO satellite constellations?

Yes! [Celestrak](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/) has several pre-arranged groups of satellites and many of those groups can be seen as constellations, and a few could be argued to be or not to be constellations as well. That's up to you.

This is not exhaustive but it is probably 90%.

[image: Celestrak's sorted TLE groupings]

The quickest way to get altitudes to decide if they are in LEO or not is to look at the mean motion, the number of orbits per 24 hour (not sidereal) day. Take this TLE (chosen at pseudo-random because I like things with 42 in them):

```
FLOCK 4S-42             
1 47612U 21006EQ  21136.74532425  .00001475  00000-0  88027-4 0  9990
2 47612  97.4946 198.5263 0010596 212.6353 147.4224 15.12647756 17251
```

It orbits about 15.12647756 times a day. To about 1 part per thousand accuracy (the Earth is lumpy and has higher order gravity terms than monopole) we can use the Earth's [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) $GM \ = \ \mu$ of 3.986E+14 m^3/s^2 and the [orbital period equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period) to estimate the semimajor axis:

$$a = \left(  \frac{\mu \ T^2}{4 \pi^2} \right) ^ {1/3}$$

The period is

$$T= \frac{24 \times 3600}{15.12647756} = 5712 \text{ seconds}$$

and so the semimajor axis is 6906397 meters or 6906 kilometers which agrees with https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=47612

[image: n2yo for Dove 4s-42]

Traditionally we subtract the Earth's equatorial radius 6378 km from that to get an "altitude" even though the Earth is not exactly spherical. In this case it would be 528 km average. This is not half-way between perigee and apogee in n2yo because they use a more precise algorithm for calculating altitudes that does include the Earth's oblate spherical shape; 6378 km is the largest value at the equator, but it's 10's of km lower near the poles.

- [How is the altitude of a satellite defined, given that the Earth is not spherical?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23842/12102)

You can choose your own cutoff for altitude to decide what is or isn't in LEO.

Then again you can try [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit)

> A low Earth orbit (LEO) is an Earth-centred orbit close to the planet, often specified as an orbital period of 128 minutes or less (making least 11.25 orbits per day) and an eccentricity less than 0.25

In this case you can just check that the mean motion in the TLE is 11.25 or greater.

If you want to apply the eccentricity <= 0.25 test also, then you can read about how the values are displayed in TLEs in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) or [here](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/documentation/tle-fmt.php).

In this case it's `0010596` and since objects in orbit have eccentricity less than 1 they supres the `0.` in front of that to save two whole columns on the ["Hollerith" punch cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card) that were used when TLEs were invented. So the eccentricity for this satellite is 0.0010596 for example.

Comment: Some of the ones that aren't on that list are likely to be state secrets.  Of various different countries even.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman for sure that might be true. I guess out of "professional courtesy" one country's satellite tracking and reporting system doesn't *publicly announce* other country's secret satellites, but private individuals do it all the time! See answers to [How (the heck) are military satellites with (apparently) classified TLEs still showing up on sat map websites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18300) They pick up radio transmissions and can track their directions and Doppler shifts, and can simply photograph their trails across the sky at night.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman now you've got me thinking; I've just asked [Has there ever been a “Find A Satellite” challenge?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52212/12102)